# self.view = mainView vs self.view.addSubview(mainView) with respect to corner radius

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I have a UIView in which I have a circular border around it. Here is the code for it:

```
let v = UIView()

self.view.addSubview(v)
v.backgroundColor = .orange

v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
v.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
v.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor).isActive = true

self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
v.layer.cornerRadius = v.frame.width / 2
```

If I set the ViewController view like this: `self.view = mainView` (mainView is a subclass of MainView which contains some other subviews), then the result of the corner radius is no longer a circle: [Resulting "circle"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyswM.png).

However, if I use `self.view.addSubview(mainView)` (and add autolayout constraints to mainView) and replace `self.view.addSubview(v)` with `self.mainView.addSubview(v)` then the circle turns out to be fine.

Why does the circle turn out weird only when I set `self.view = mainView`, but is fine when I do `self.view.addSubview(mainView)`?

Comment: Because you have to add the main view as the subview. self.view = mainView cannot be main view

Comment: @User511 I thought that it was possible to set the view of a ViewController by setting it equal to another view?

Comment: But that should be your subview

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point. However, what you've posted isn't enough for me to reproduce something I think I can help you with. What is the *minimal* thing for me to do that?

Comment: @dfd If you create a view with a circular border as I did above with the view "v", and set the view controller's view to something else (self.view = mainView), then the circular view will remain a square. I tried to reproduce the same image as above in a new project but it seems that the weird circle is caused by a constraint that is a subview of a subview of mainView in my actual project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First where are you replacing the UIViewControllers view with mainView?  You should be overriding the loadView method of the UIViewController not doing it in the viewDidLoad method.

Second if you are changing the UIViewControllers view then it will not have it's frame setup when you get to viewDidLoad like the original will and so the UIView v is getting the incorrect layout size which it is then using to determine its corner radius.

Third you shouldn't use layoutIfNeeded in the viewDidLoad as this is way to early to be trying to determine the final layout of the main view (everything is still loading).  What you should be doing is overriding viewDidLLayoutSubviews method and setting the corner radius there like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    v.layer.cornerRadius = v.frame.width / 2
}
```

What that also does is if the size of the UIView v changes (orientation change, etc) then it will remain a circle at it's new size otherwise it will just have rounded corners.

Of course you have to make UIView v a class instance variable in order to be able to access it here.

Comment: Oh wow, I had a lot of problems with my view controller. Thanks for clearing it all up! @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.